# Defining area of influence for origin-destination dataset (where destination is port) using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arctoolbox, flow, origin-destination

Starting from an origin-destination dataset for a given country, where the origins are city (points) and the destination are ports (points), how can I identify the area of influence for each particular port?

Is there a tool in ArcMap which can automate the creation of the polygons for showing which region is more key to one port or another?

Comment: Do you have access to the network analyst extension?

Comment: create service area sounds like a tool that could help http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004700000048000000

Comment: @Maksim, yes I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Network Analyst, using the [Location Allocation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Location_allocation_analysis/004700000050000000/) tool.

Input your origins as facilities, and destinations as demand points. This should give you a result of associated points, which then can be used to create polygons using either Feature to Polygon or Construct Polygon, [Help Site](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//01m600000015000000)